# Django install issue

Tags: python, django, installation

I was installing Django and was working through the steps when I ran `python setup.py install`. It was not recognized as an external or internal command. I did change the path to `C:\Python27;`.

Comment: try to make `c:\Python27` to `c:\Python27/bin;`, and then check it.

Comment: This probably means that you aren't setting your `PATH` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set your `PATH` environment variable to include:

```
C:\Python27
```

If you install [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip), you'll also want to add:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts
```

to your `PATH`